# Number Theory over $\mathbb{F}_q [t]$, why is it important/interesting?

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question

This is something I was curious about, but not really sure why. I was hoping maybe someone could give me a good explanation. I understand that there are 
similarities between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$
is a finite field of $q$ elements. And many interesting results in number theory 
over $\mathbb{Z}$ have an $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$-analogue. When we have some result over $\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}$), and we consider these analogues, do we generalize to $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$ (or $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$) just for the sake of generalizing it to a different setting? or are there more reasons why this generalization to $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$ is interesting to consider? Thank you!

Comment: A possible duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1367/global-fields-what-exactly-is-the-analogy-between-number-fields-and-function-fi

Comment: One way number theory in the function field case ($\mathbf F_q(t)$ and its finite extensions) can be applied back to more classical problems is in strong estimates on classical exponential sums. The best estimates are usually obtained from analogues of the Riemann hypothesis for zeta-functions or $L$-functions in function fields. By the way, in your question, the analogue of $\mathbf R$ in the function field case is *not* the rational function field $\mathbf F_q(t)$ but Laurent series fields such as  $\mathbf F_q((t))$ and $\mathbf F_q((1/t))$.

Comment: Peter Scholze's ongoing course at Berkeley is a striking example of this analogy, using insights and constructions from the function field case to develop new ideas and techniques in the characteristic 0 case (and perfectoid spaces have opened up striking ways to directly use char. p geometry to solve problems in char. 0). The use of Ngo's results on the Fundamental Lemma in char. p to solve the analogous problem in char. 0 is another fantastic example (deeply ramified extensions in char. 0 can be "approximated" by analogous extensions in char. p).

Comment: The Ax-Kochen theorem is an early example of how one can infer theorems on number fields from the analogous ones on function fields. The wikipedia page has a good summary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Kochen_theorem

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments! They are very interesting and helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: @KConrad I edited my mistake. I meant to write $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ there. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Since no one pointed out. Lower basis like $\mathbb{F}_1$ are important (conjectural) constructions to solve theorems like the Riemann hypothesis (that can be solved for finite fields). And a lot of unknown stuffs are known for global function fields, so this analogy would be important in this context..

Comment: @user40276: Scholze's course is an instance of what you are referring to (except focused towards the local Langlands correspondence rather than the Riemann Hypothesis). However, it takes the idea of "geometry over $\mathbf{F}_1$" solely as inspiration (along with V. Lafforgue's recent work on global Langlands for reductive groups), rather than trying to define something like $\mathbf{F}_1$ (as that is entirely unnecessary). This leads to novel constructions with perfectoid spaces and ideas related to algebraic spaces, including a notion of mixed-characteristic shtuka.