# $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^d)$ is separable

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I Think the statement is true, but I struggle to find a reference for the fact that the space of tempered distributions equipped with the weak-* topology is separable. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Finite linear combinations of $\delta$'s and their derivatives of arbitrary order looks dense, and you can make all data rational. I haven't thought this through very carefully, and anyway, this question seems much better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: why so many votes to close? One could say this is a "basic question" in the theory of distributions and therefore perhaps more suited for math.stackexchange. But how many textbooks on distributions contain the answers to such basic questions?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean by separable the existence of a countable dense subset the answer is yes.
One can see this as follows.
Let $\mathcal{s}$ be the space of sequences $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers
for which all the seminorms
$$
||x||_{k}=\sup_{n\ge 0} (n+1)^k|x_n|\ ,
$$
$k\in\mathbb{N}$, are finite (I am using Bourbaki's convention of counting from zero).
Equip this space with the locally convex topology generated by the countable collection of seminorms $||\cdot||_k$, $k\ge 0$. Let $\mathcal{s}'$ be the topological dual equipped with the weak-$\ast$ topology. Then $S'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{s}'$ and therefore your question can be reduced to the much more concrete case of the space $\mathcal{s}'$. The latter can (even more concretely!) be realized as the space of sequences $y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers such that there exists a $k\ge 0$ and a constant $C$ for which
$$
|y_n|\le C(n+1)^k
$$
for all $n$.
The duality pairing is given by
$$
y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y_n x_n\ .
$$
Now let $D=\oplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Q}\subset \mathcal{s}'$, namely the set of almost finite sequences of rational numbers. $D$ is countable and dense.

Indeed let $y\in\mathcal{s}'$, let $x^{(1)},\ldots,x^{(p)}$ be in $\mathcal{s}$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Clearly, there exists a $z\in D$ such that for all $q$, $1\le q\le p$,
$$
|(z-y)(x^{(q)})|<\epsilon\ .
$$
Since the series defining the $y(x^{(q)})$ converge, truncate them far enough and approximate the corresponding finite sequence of terms in $y$ by rationals.

---

Addendum as per Eric's comment: the isomorphism between $S'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mathcal{s}'$ is very well explained (using Hermite functions) in the article ["Distributions and Their Hermite Expansions"](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/12/1/10.1063/1.1665472) by Barry Simon.
It is funny how little known this thing is. I think also it is an open problem to find an explicit isomorphism (or Schauder basis) between $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ and $\oplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{s}$, see [this other MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187404/isomorphisms-between-spaces-of-test-functions-and-sequence-spaces).

Comment: Why is $S'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ isomorphic to $s'$?

Comment: Speaking of standard textbooks, this argument appears as Appendix to §V.3 in Reed & Simon, vol.1. The result about separability is in Corollary 2 (p.144).

Comment: @Igor: Reed and Simon is standard among mathematical physicists, but I don't know if it so for the majority of users of the theory of distributions. In any case, Barry Simon did much to emphasize this sequence space connection.

Comment: @Eric: see the reference in my edit, or the book mentioned by Igor.

Answer (score 2):

Very generally, any dual of a space of continuous functions on a separable space is weak*-separable.  More precisely, let $A$ be any topological space, let $B\subseteq A$ be a dense subset, and let $S$ be any vector space of continuous real-valued functions on $A$.  Then I claim that $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of evaluations $\delta_b$ at points $b\in B$ are dense in the full linear dual $S'$ with the weak* topology (and thus also in the continuous dual for any topology on $S$ that makes each $\delta_b$ continuous).

To show this, let $U\subset S'$ be a nonempty open set; then $U$ contains a subset of the form $$\{\alpha\in S': \alpha(f_1)\in V_1, \alpha(f_2)\in V_2,\dots,\alpha(f_n)\in V_n\}$$
where $f_1,\dots f_n\in S$ are linearly independent functions and $V_1,\dots,V_n\subset\mathbb{R}$ are nonempty and open.  Since $B$ is dense in $A$, we can find points $b_1,\dots,b_n\in B$ such that the restrictions of the $f_i$ to $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ are still linearly independent (prove this by induction on $n$).  We thus have a perfect pairing between the span of the $f_i$ and the span of the functionals $\delta_{b_i}$.  Since the $V_i$ are open, it follows that we can find a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of the $\delta_{b_i}$ which is in our $U$.